# Can I use automator to select text then search spotlight for it?

Tags: automator, services

Basically, I have a spreadsheet of file names.  I want to select a file name and search 4 folders simultaneously for it.
I'd prefer for all the results to be listed in 1 Finder or 1 Spotlight window, but that's not necessary.
I feel like it should be something I can do with an Automator service that receives selected text but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest you are going to get is something like this.

( In a Automator **Service**  Document )

[image]

I am just show two folders here as an example.

The first action gathers the selected text into a variable.

Each Spotlight Action ignore the above actions output/input and uses the variable token as the search term.